# Terminating socket connection when receiving newline

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to create a mechanism where my server stops reading input after it encounters only a newline.

Here is the code (most of it taken from MSDN examples):

```
private void ReadRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    SocketState state = (SocketState) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    try
    {
        int read = handler.EndReceive(ar);
        if (read > 0)
        {
            string line = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, read);
            byte[] temp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);
            string hex = BitConverter.ToString(temp);
            eventLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("Bytes read: {0}, Content: {1}, Hex: {2}", line.Length, line, hex));
            if (line.Equals(Environment.NewLine) || line.Equals('\n'))
            {
                eventLog.WriteEntry("Double line break.");
                string response = HandleRequest(state.sb.ToString());
                handler.BeginSend(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response), 0, response.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendDone), state);
                return;
            }

            state.sb.Append(line);
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, SocketState.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadRequest), state);
        }
        else
        {
            string response = HandleRequest(state.sb.ToString());
            eventLog.WriteEntry(response, EventLogEntryType.Information);
            handler.BeginSend(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response), 0, response.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendDone), state);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("Error occured while reading the request: {0}", exception.Message), EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
}
```

But the newline condition is never true and so the server never stops reading input.

I print out the hex characters of what I send and when I connect using netcat:

```
C:\WINDOWS> nc localhost 55432
Foo<newline>
<newline>
```

Sure enough, the last line that is sent to the server is:

```
Bytes read: 1, Content: 
, Hex: 0A
```

I've checked and `0A` is hex for `\n`, so why does my check not work?

Comment: Perhaps check `line.Length == 1 && line[0] == '\n'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As line is a string and '\n' is a char, those are never equal.

You should either check for equal strings or chars:

```
if (line.Equals(Environment.NewLine) || line == "\n")
```

or

```
if ((line.length > 0 && line[0] == '\n') || (line.length > 1 && line[0] == '\r' && line[1] == '\n'))
```